# scrapy crawl only returns saves one result to csv file

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this scrapy spider

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from items import QuestionItem


class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'first'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions']

    def parse(self, response):

        selector_list = response.css('.question-summary')

        for selector in selector_list:
            item = QuestionItem()
            item['question'] = selector.css('h3 a::text').extract()
            item['votes'] = selector.css('.vote-count-post strong::text').extract()
            item['answers'] = selector.css('.status strong::text').extract()
            item['views'] = selector.css('.views ::text').extract()[0].replace('\n','').replace('\r','').lstrip()
            item['username'] = selector.css('.user-details a::text').extract()
            item['userlink'] = selector.css('.user-details a::attr(href)').extract()

        return item
```

with this code also in items.py

```
import scrapy

class QuestionItem(scrapy.Item):
    question = scrapy.Field()
    votes = scrapy.Field()
    answers = scrapy.Field()
    views = scrapy.Field(serializer=str)
    username = scrapy.Field()
    userlink = scrapy.Field()
```

it's supposed to start on the default questions page of stackoverflow and get all questions using the css tag.
It however only saves one row to csv when using this command.
`scrapy crawl first --output file.csv`

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `return` statement in your `parse` method, when executed the function terminates.

You should do use `yield` instead of `return` and that too inside your for loop's scope.

```
class FirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'first'
    allowed_domains = ['stackoverflow.com']
    start_urls = ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions']

    def parse(self, response):

        selector_list = response.css('.question-summary')

        for selector in selector_list:
            item = QuestionItem()
            item['question'] = selector.css('h3 a::text').extract()
            item['votes'] = selector.css('.vote-count-post strong::text').extract()
            item['answers'] = selector.css('.status strong::text').extract()
            item['views'] = selector.css('.views ::text').extract()[0].replace('\n','').replace('\r','').lstrip()
            item['username'] = selector.css('.user-details a::text').extract()
            item['userlink'] = selector.css('.user-details a::attr(href)').extract()

            yield item
```